# How to access my Liked Songs in Spotify (Python)

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I want to do a project where I access and analyze my Liked Songs in Spotify.

I was wondering what is the best way to access my Liked Songs? Is it the same way as getting the playlist via Spotipy? Is there another package that can access the list of songs in Liked Songs?

Any pseudocode/documentation/example would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried searching for anything yet? Got this from the 2nd google result: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-users-saved-tracks

Comment: https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/show_my_saved_tracks.py is this what you are looking for? You can find the whole documentation of the Spotipy API here: https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/

Comment: @peter I did not see that the first time, as I was specifically looking for the keyword 'liked songs' (First time playing with API)

Answer (score 1):

Once authenticated with Spotipy, you can use it to retrieve your liked songs using the endpoint [current_user_saved_tracks()](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/#spotipy.client.Spotify.current_user_saved_tracks)